# Laravel 4 - Where to call View::share

Tags: php, view, laravel-4, laravel-routing

all

I know `View::share` should be available **anywhere** within my application,  A common place is in my `routes.php` file.

I am doing this.

1) User login system, after login successfully,  share something for all the views.

2) when user click other pages, can use the shared variables.

Ok, my controller.

```
public function index() {
    $data = array(
        "pageTitle" => "index",
    );

    $privilegeMenu = $this->privilegeApi->getUserPrivilegeByUserId(Session::get('uid'));
    $topMenus = $this->menuApi->getTopMenuById($privilegeMenu);
    $subMenus = $this->menuApi->getSubMenuesById($privilegeMenu);

    View::share('topMenus', $topMenus);
    View::share('subMenus', $subMenus);

    return View::make('home.index',$data);
}
```

So, because I am using View share, that it is to say, in every other views, I can use `topMenus` and `subMenus` now.

But when I click other pages, I got the error: `Undefined variable: topMenus`.

So, I am so confused what happened? I dive into View::share source code

Laravel have a class named `Environment` under `namespace Illuminate\View`.

```
protected $shared = array();

public function share($key, $value = null)
{
    if ( ! is_array($key)) return $this->shared[$key] = $value;

    foreach ($key as $innerKey => $innerValue)
    {
        $this->share($innerKey, $innerValue);
    }
}

public function shared($key, $default = null)
{
    return array_get($this->shared, $key, $default);
}
```

And I found when user login successfully, `topMenus` shared successfully. But when I click other pages, can't `topMenus` in `shared`.

It seems everything OK, I am confused. Any one knows ?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `View::share` statement is never ran for other routes. **In Laravel 4.x**, there are quite a few places you could put it where it would be ran every time, but these two are most commonly used:

1. The easiest and most simple way is to just add it at the end of your `app/start/global.php` which is ran at the *start* of every request, for all environments.
2. The other way is to create a new service provider, make sure it's autoloadable and add it to your `app/config/app.php`'s `providers` array.

If all you want is share a few views, I'd say it's kinda of an overkill to create a whole new class just for that. If, however, you start noticing your `app/start/global.php` file is getting too cluttered, I'd recommend you start splitting stuff into service providers.

**PS:** In Laravel 5, `app/start/global.php` was removed and you're left only with the second option.

Comment: thanks. I've never used provider, if I create a provider, how can I put the shared variables and how can I make sure all the view can access it and how can I visit the variables? I read the whole doc but not found the usage doc. Thanks very much.